# AWS Access/Secret Keys on first login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve IAM access keys on first login. The idea is that I will have a set number of IAM accounts with temporary passwords, when a client signs into their relevant account they are asked to change their password and once changed, they are provided with their access/secret key. This key will then be stored within the secure storage/key store on a mobile application. They can then make requests to a custom AWS API (API Gateway) using these stored keys. Is there some way that we can retrieve these keys through some request on initial login? Rather than in the AWS Console? Thanks for any suggestions or ideas :)

Comment: This is exactly what [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) does for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look into that, thanks. Another question, are you aware of their being anyway to login/check authentication for Amazon Cognito offline or what the implications behind that are. My mobile app needs to be able to work with no internet connection.

Comment: Check out [AWS Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws); it’ll help solve a lot of these challenges for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't believe Amplify will work for me unfortunately. I am building my application as a cross-platform Xamarin-Forms application for Android and iOS